# How to force caja to open other windows in tabs?

Tags: linux-mint, caja

I’m using linux mint 17. The file manager is caja (fork of nautilus). It’s work fine. But I wish to open every window of files browser in one window of caja in tabbed. Please, could you tell me how to do, thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

since caja 1.22 (linux mint 19.2) it's possible with -t in caja command line